# PHPMailer debugging fatal error

Tags: php, debugging, phpmailer

I have a form that on submit is supposed to run my php file, but I believe I keep getting fatal error. At the end of my php file I have this block of code:

```
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

But when I hit submit to execute my php file all that happens is the page is redirected to my php file and is a blank webpage. I don't see any of the echo's. Kind of new to PHP and PHPMailer so if someone could tell me how to debug php code that would be greatly appreciated.

This is my mail setup, I am trying to send an email through my web server to outlook:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port = '995';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Comment: ALWAYS the first step when you have a problem with server side php is to check the error the http server outputs inside its error log file. Everything else is wild guessing.

Comment: @arkascha you're saying the php log?

Comment: Which file it is depends on your php configuration, only you can say. Typically it is the http servers error log file, something like `/var/log/apache2/error_log` or similar, but that depends on your system setup and can be changed inside the `php.ini` configuration file.

Comment: @arkascha In my `php.ini` file I have: `error_log = ".\php_errors.log"` but that log file is empty. and `log_errors = On`

Comment: I have never seen a relative location to be specified. That makes little sense. Reconfigure it to use the "normal" system logging facility I suggest and make sure you restart the http server process afterwards so that the change gets applied.

Comment: @arkascha when you say "normal system logging facility" what do you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45484/discussion-between-arkascha-and-metsales)

Comment: @arkascha ok, sorry it took so long for the response I'm in the chat.

Comment: @arkascha on my page with the form if my action is set to the php file, do I need to have this `<?php include 'sendDemo.php'; ?>` on the form page?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot really say without you showing the code. The "form" page you mention most likely is a html page you see in your browser. PHP does not belong in an html page. In case that html page has been generated by a php script getting executed then you most likely do _not_ need that include command, since aparently the html page is generated correctly without. For everything else I have to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your object instantiation is incorrect. It should be:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Also, you can modify php [runtime configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to view errors: `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors`

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: This does not help if his clients gets redirected. He will not see any error hint.

Comment: @arkascha anyway I can prevent the redirect? I do have JQuery running, and I tried a few things that on submit should stop the redirect, but it doesn't seem to work. this is my jquery code: `$('#dform').submit(function (event) {
  alert("Your request has been submitted. Please allow at least 1 business day for a response.");
  return false;
 });`

Comment: Well if you make a normal form post then you ask to be redirected to the php script. Otherwise you have to make the post using AJAX, but I doubt that is what you want to do. Solve the problem instead of trying around.